# How do you set up nvidia mps daemon to launch at boot time on arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, cuda

I've tried searching the web, and I can't find anything that just gives a command on how to get systemctl to enable it. I've tried having systemctl list the installed and I couldn't find anything on it even though I've got nvidia-utils installed. Does the nvidia daemon just not have a unit file for systemd? I've also tried checking out the section on utilities and daemons [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/mps/index.html#topic_5_1), and it didn't mention anything about starting it at boot. I've also tried reading the arch wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GPGPU#CUDA), and it didn't have anything either.

Comment: Can you give us a few more details please? What service are you trying to enable? Have you run `systemctl enable foo.service`? Is it even a service? How is `nvidia-utils` relevant? What is this "nvidia daemon" you speak of?

Comment: I'm trying to enable the nvidia cuda multi-process service daemon. systemctl doesn't enable it. nvidia-utils is the package that the daemon is found in.